# Can I disable a helicopter by ramming?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

Is it possible to disable a helicopter in a pursuit by ramming when it tries to land on me? If so, how hard should I hit it?

Comment: What do you mean by hit it in "hit it"? Do you mean how much you should go away from helicopter?

Comment: I don't see how you would be able to hit a helicopter when it is flying and you are on the ground.

Comment: Actually, especially at Heat Level 5, helicopters try to land on the player's car, but often they land a bit in front of it, thus the possibility of ramming. @Dragonrage

Comment: That sounds like a fantastic bit of info to add to the question.

Comment: @Frank but surely anyone who can answer this, knows the game well enough to know 'how' you can ram a helicopter.... ?

Comment: @djsmiley2k And for those who don't, we go, "Wha?  How does that even work?  It's a racing game!"  While it's not needed, context can help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to wreck the helicopter just by directly ramming into it, but it is possible to wreck it with the help of a pursuit breaker, if you get lucky.

For example, blowing up a gas station with a helicopter above it will wreck the heli, but getting the heli to hover above the gas station without the rest of the ground forces cornering you or blowing up the gas station themselves will take some work.

Comment: I already knew that destroying ANY pursuit breaker with an helicopter above will destroy it. Even destroying a wooden pavilion would work. @NoirAntares